# Convexity of multi variate functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.

I know $f(x)$ is convex if its Hessian ($\frac{\partial^2  f(x)}{\partial  x\partial  x^T}$) is positive semi-definite.

Now, let $g(t)=f(x_0+t\Delta x)$ ($t\in \mathbb{R}$) for some arbitrary $x_0,\Delta x\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I have the following questions:

1- Is it correct that if $g(t)$ is convex in $t$ for any $x_0,\Delta x\in \mathbb{R}^m$, then $f(x)$ is convex in $x$?

2- If the answer is no in general, under what conditions it holds? And, if the answer is yes, is there any proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: by the definition of convexity, it suffices to show $(1-\lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b) \ge f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b)$ for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and any $x,y$. If $g$ is as you define it with $x_0:= a$ and $\Delta x := b-a$, then the above inequality is equivalent to $(1-\lambda) g(0) + \lambda g(1) \ge g(\lambda)$, which holds by assumed convexity of $g$.

Comment: Thanks! A follow up question, since this method seems to work well in asserting if a (highly complicated) multivariate function is convex or not, why do people bother proving if its Hessian is PSD? (I'm confused here a little bit, because showing if a variable matrix is PSD all the times is not trivial for me.) What's the catch?

Comment: @Alt If $f$ is twice differentiable, then in some sense both methods are the same. Recall that one definition of PSD-ness of a matrix $H$ is checking $v^\top H v \ge 0$ for all directions $v$. So, checking convexity of $g$ for every $x_0$ and $\Delta x$ [using the second derivative] is like checking $(\Delta x)^\top (\nabla^2 f (x_0)) (\Delta x) \ge 0$ for every $x_0$ and $\Delta x$.

Comment: @Alt If the Hessian has a nice form, it may be easier to verify its PSD-ness using other tricks, so that is one advantage of using the Hessian. However, note that the approach using $g$ works even when $f$ is not twice differentiable.